# How do I get the date of the first day of a given week?

Tags: vbscript

Given:

```
weekNumber = 45, 
year = 2016
```

The conditions for the first week:

- Starts with monday
- vbFirstFourDays - Start with the week that has at least four days in the new year

How do i get the Date `'Monday 07.11.2016' (dd.mm.yyyy)` with the given data?

Comment: i have the weeknumber and the year.. i need to get the date 07.11.2016

Comment: `DateAdd("ww", weekNumber, DateSerial(year,1,1))` will get you close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Since the accepted answer has still wrong results</s> I do a comparison here.

```
Option Explicit
Dim year, wn, wd, wk, Jan4, wdn, wno, nDay, Out

wn = 45

For year = 2012 to 2018
  Wscript.Echo "LotPings : " & ShowDate(DateYWkWd(year,wn,1)) 
  Wscript.Echo "Lankymart: " & Showdate(Lankymart(year,wn))
  Wscript.Echo "duDE     : " & Showdate(     duDE(year,wn))
  Wscript.Echo
Next

Function DateYWkWd(year, wn, wd)
  ' returns date based von VbMondeay and vbFirstFourDays
  Jan4 = Dateserial(year,1,4) ' garantied to be in first week
  DateYWkWd = DateAdd("ww",wn-1, DateAdd("d",wd-Weekday(Jan4,2),Jan4))
end Function

Function Lankymart(year, wn)
  wd = DateAdd("ww", wn, DateSerial(year,1,1))
  Lankymart = wd - WeekDay(wd, vbMonday) + 1
end Function

Function duDE(year, wn)
  nDay = 4 + (wn - 1)*7 - 1
  duDE = DateAdd("d", nDay, DateSerial(year,1,1))
end Function

Function ShowDate(date)
  Wd  = Weekday(date,vbMonday)
  Wdn = WeekDayName(Wd, True,vbMonday)
  Wno = datepart("ww", date, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
  Out = Wdn & " " & date & " WeekNo : " & Wno
  If Wno <> wn Then Out = Out & " **wrong week **"
  If Wd  <> 1  Then Out = Out & " **wrong wkday**"
  ShowDate = Out
end Function
```

Here the output. The Function DateYWkWd could be unsed universally
Providing year, week number and day of week (1=Mon..7=Sun)

```
LotPings : Mon 11/5/2012 WeekNo : 45
Lankymart: Mon 11/5/2012 WeekNo : 45
duDE     : Wed 11/7/2012 WeekNo : 45 **wrong wkday**

LotPings : Mon 11/4/2013 WeekNo : 45
Lankymart: Mon 11/11/2013 WeekNo : 46 **wrong week **
duDE     : Fri 11/8/2013 WeekNo : 45 **wrong wkday**

LotPings : Mon 11/3/2014 WeekNo : 45
Lankymart: Mon 11/10/2014 WeekNo : 46 **wrong week **
duDE     : Sat 11/8/2014 WeekNo : 45 **wrong wkday**

LotPings : Mon 11/2/2015 WeekNo : 45
Lankymart: Mon 11/9/2015 WeekNo : 46 **wrong week **
duDE     : Sun 11/8/2015 WeekNo : 45 **wrong wkday**

LotPings : Mon 11/7/2016 WeekNo : 45
Lankymart: Mon 11/7/2016 WeekNo : 45
duDE     : Mon 11/7/2016 WeekNo : 45

LotPings : Mon 11/6/2017 WeekNo : 45
Lankymart: Mon 11/6/2017 WeekNo : 45
duDE     : Wed 11/8/2017 WeekNo : 45 **wrong wkday**

LotPings : Mon 11/5/2018 WeekNo : 45
Lankymart: Mon 11/12/2018 WeekNo : 46 **wrong week **
duDE     : Thu 11/8/2018 WeekNo : 45 **wrong wkday**
```

Comment: Oh i didn't look up on 2018.. Thank you

Comment: The Function DateYWkWd() answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a combination of `DateAdd()` and `WeekDay()` functions without having to perform manual calculations.

```vb
Dim year: year = 2016
Dim wn: wn = 45
Dim wd: wd = DateAdd("ww", wn, DateSerial(year,1,1))

WScript.Echo wd - WeekDay(wd, vbMonday) + 1
```

Output:

```
07/11/2016
```

---

**Update:**

Put this together in 5 minutes and with minimal testing seemed to do the trick, but as [@lotpings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) [answer proves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40516748/692942) in certain years it will still fail. It was just a quick stab and their answer is definitely the correct approach to use.

Comment: @Bene + Lankymart, sorry but the result will only give correct results in years where the weekday of Jan 1st is friday to sunday. This is true for this and the next year, but fails in 2018. A better way is to determine the weekday of the Jan 4th, because this is shure to be the first week.

Answer (score 0):

So you can get the day by

```
4 + (45 - 1)*7 - 1 = 311
```

because the first week has only 4 days and the remaining 44 weeks have 7 days.

Now you can get the date by DateAdd:

```
Dim nDay
nDay = 4 + (45 - 1)*7 - 1

Dim NewDate
NewDate = DateAdd("d", nDay, DateSerial(2016,1,1))

MsgBox NewDate
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. how about next year? If I am typing week 1 with 01.01.2017 i get the first wensday instead of monday..

Comment: I'd use `NewDate = DateAdd("d", nDay, DateSerial(2016,1,1))` to avoid local formatting issues.

Comment: i am still getting 04.01.2017 instead of 02.01.2017.. do i need to change the algorithm for 2017?

Comment: The question is, whether the 2017 starts with the week that has at least four days in the new year - if not, you need to change the algorythm accordantly.